# R Markdown could not find function

Tags: r, r-markdown

Running Compile Notebook from RStudio.

I am getting:

> ```
> Error: could not find function "SegNeigh"
> ```

"SegNeigh" being my own function, properly sourced; the script runs fine without R Markdown.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order for the rmarkdown doc to find the function, you either need to define `SegNeigh` in the same document or place it in another file and source that file explicitly

Comment: By sourced explicitly you mean, sourced inside the script that's being executed. That means, current R environment does not count. I see now, thanks.