# Why does R Markdown not want to Knit with spss file?

Tags: r, r-markdown, knitr, spss

I performed a multilevel analysis in R (following Kay Chansiri's tutorial but using my df). It worked as it should, but then I wanted to do it again in R Markdown so as to make it into a report. The code works fine in R Markdown, but it will not knit it. Everything seems to revolve around the spss file I am using.

Here is the code from the first chunk:

````
```{r MLM_deJong}
MLM_deJong<-read_sav("dataset_MA2.sav")
View(MLM_deJong)
```
````

And the next chunk:

````
```{r}
MLM_deJong = MLM_deJong %>% replace_with_na(replace = list(business = 999))
mean(MLM_deJong$business, na.rm = T)

MLM_deJong$business[is.na(MLM_deJong$business)] <- mean(MLM_deJong$business, na.rm = T)
```
````

and so on...

R imports the df and performs all the operations. But when I want to knit it, here is what the R Markdown tab in the console writes:

> Line 46Error in read_sav("dataset_MA2.sav) : could not find function "read_sav" calls: ... handle -> withCallHandlers -> withVisible -> eval -> eval.

Needless to mention, no file is knit.

I have of course installed the 'haven' package. The same occurs when I tried `read.spss` through the 'foreign' package.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [R Markdown could not find function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30745003/r-markdown-could-not-find-function)

Answer (score 0):

Even though you have installed the haven package, it is not automatically loaded when rmarkdown knits.

Option 1: Load the haven package before you use it.

```r
library(haven)
MLM_deJong<-read_sav("dataset_MA2.sav")
```

Option 2: Prepend `haven::` to `read_sav`

```r
MLM_deJong<-haven::read_sav("dataset_MA2.sav")
```